# Help me probability problem?

Tags: probability

There are 3 people A,B,C are arrested to prison, then they hear that 2 among 3 of them will be released. A asked the prison keeper that who will be release among B and C ? And the prison keeper reply that: "now the probability of you are release is 2/3, so if I let you know who will be release among B and C, the probability you are release will decrease to 1/2. I don't want your probability decrease so I don't tell you". And the explanation of the prison keeper is right or wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $\Omega = \{(A,B), (A, C), (B,C)\}$ are all of the possible outcomes. If $E = \{(A,B), (A,C)\}$ is the events when $A$ is released, then $P(E) = \frac{|E|}{|\Omega|} = \frac{2}{3}$. Now let's denote with $F$ the event when $B$ is released : $F = \{(A,B), (B,C)\}$ ($P(F) = \frac{2}{3}$). Then the conditional probability $P(E | F)$ (the probability of $E$ to occur if we know that $F$ is occured) is

$$P(E|F) = \frac{P(E \cap F)}{P(F)} = \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Same think if we know that $C$ will be released. So the prison keeper is right.

Comment: The prison keeper could tell prisoner $A$ that prisoner $B$ is being released, that prisoner $C$ is being released, or that both prisoners $B$ and $C$ are being released.

Comment: No @N.F.Taussig , I guess, he always says only name (no matter if they both will be released).